# Correct way of indicating period of time on this sentence

Tags: grammar, time

Between the sentences:

- You've only been a day there.
- You've only been there for a day.

Which would the grammatically correct one, or both are correct?

Thank you

Comment: The second one sounds right to my ears.

Comment: Neither is incorrect, but the second is better.

Comment: Thank you Elgs and Kate. 2nd also sounds better for me, but couldn't find anything wrong with the 1st one.

Comment: I'm going to say that [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+been+there+a+day%2Conly+been+a+day+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20been%20there%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0) support my judgement that 'You've only been a day there' is incorrect because it is unidiomatic. 'You've only been a day in Lisbon' etc may well be found in old-fashioned literature. / Preposition deletion is not incorrect per se; 'You've only been there a day' is at least as common as 'You've only been there for a day'....

Comment: [Here are included further Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+been+there+a+day%2Conly+been+a+day+there%2Cbeen+there+a+day%2C+been+there+for+a+day%2C+been+a+day+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20been%20there%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20there%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20there%20for%20a%20day%3B%2Cc0) in support of this claim. (Click on 'search lots of books' to 'see' the missing Ngrams.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is right. Where are you? There. How long have you been-there? A day.

Conversely, "I spent five days there." The days are what was spent. *There* is where I spent-five-days.